# How to monitor kafka 0.10.0 running on remote machine using jmx?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmx

I am using kafka 0.10.0 which is running both in local and remote machine.
When i run "jvisualvm" command in terminal  its open Java VisualVM window and shows all java application including kafka which is running in local machine.

But when i tried to access kafka 0.10.0 which is running in remote machine it shows error message can not connect to server

[image]

How to monitor kafka 0.10.0 running on remote machine using jmx?

Edit 1===>
I start the kafka server using command

```
 JMX_PORT=9999 bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Also verified process in pointing using command

```
netstat -nlp | grep :9999
```

Output: tcp6 0 0 :::9999 :::* LISTEN 5429/java

But when i try connect through my local machine its giving same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify JMX_PORT in the kafka-server-start shell script before doing the monitoring.

Comment: Please check Edit 1 Comments

Comment: Are there any firewall policy or iptables settings preventing the connection? For example, a RMI port will randomly selected to connect to JMX port.

Comment: Got fixed using t SSH SOCKS proxy connection

Answer (score 0):

Start your kafka server using below commands :

**JMX_PORT=9999 bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties**

Once server started , open jconsole or Java VM on your local machine and start monitoring the Kafka server.